# Why does the contains() method in Java not work as expected?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains

I am writing a method that creates an ArrayList `S_Comp` that contains all elements which are included in the array `allNodes`, but which are not included in the ArrayList `solution` (whose elements are all included in `allNodes`). When I print `solution` and `allNodes`, I can easily see that `S_Comp` should be containing 7 elements. However, all elements from `allNodes` are added to `S_Comp`, also the elements which are included in `nodesS`. What could be the problem here?

Below you can find my code for the method. Before calling this method, `S_Comp` has only been initialized as `new ArrayList<MyNodesData>`, so its size is 0.

```
public void generateSComp(DataFile testDataFile, ArrayList<Route> solution, ArrayList<MyNodesData> S_Comp)
    {
        System.out.println("solution: " + solution.toString());
        ArrayList<MyNodesData> nodesS = getNodesS(solution);
        System.out.println("NodesS: " + nodesS.toString());
        System.out.println("Size nodesS: " + nodesS.size());
        MyNodesData[] allNodes = testDataFile.getNodes();
        System.out.println("allNodes: " + Arrays.toString(allNodes));
        for(MyNodesData node : allNodes)
        {
            if(!nodesS.contains(node))
            {
                System.out.println(node.toShortString() + " is not in nodesS");
                S_Comp.add(node);
            }
        }
```

Comment: does MyNodesData implements hashCode and equals?

Comment: @Michal it does not, but .contains() used to work properly on MyNodesData earlier

Comment: @Mike Oh god, with our 3 names this is going to be so confusing... Without overriding equals, `contains` is using reference equality. If the objects are distinct instances with the same fields then `contains` will return false.

Comment: without overriding equals,  equals method() compares references (take a look into Object.class). So as long as you work with the same objects it works. If you create new objects with same attribute values it doesn't work anymore

Comment: @Mike not without those two methods, it won't

Comment: @Stultuske `contains` can work fine without `equals` if you're careful about how the objects are created. For example, if all objects come from an object pool then it's not required.

Comment: @Michael it's fragile though. Like in this case it's possible that OP changed how the nodes are created somewhere else and break `contains` here.

Comment: @Michael since that's usually not the case ... and since that can't really be forced (for most datatypes) within the class ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer here for the contains method of ArrayList javadoc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-

It says

> public boolean contains(Object o)
>
> Returns true if this list contains  the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this
>   list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null :
>   o.equals(e)).

So it will work only if you **override equals method of Object Class** as you want **in MyNodesData class**. Moreover as you may already be knowing the contract between equals() and hashcode() method, it is **highly recommended to override hashcode() along with equals()**.

For more information : [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

contains works just as expected, it will check if the object you pass `equals` the object in the list. So if you are not getting the expected behavior is because those objects do not equal.

You will have to debug that code to check why the equals is not returning what you expect.

Edit: I read that you are not overriding equals and hashcode in MyNodesData class, so you should do it as other people suggest

Answer (score 0):

override hashcode and equals method in MyNodesData class and then check.